# Home page is not loading after Upgrade Magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

[image]

After upgrading magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3 Home page content is not loading perfectly.Css is appears instead of homepage.Is there anyone who can guide me to accomplish that?

Comment: First try to check log files under **var -> log** folder, and add **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** in app/bootstrap.php file to know whether it is due to any PHP error.

Comment: First set the developer mode. 
follow this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354434/frontend-is-breaks-on-magento-2-4-3/354445#354445

Answer (score 0):

please check the PHP version. Magento 2.4.3 supports the 7.4 PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Run all the magento commands-

```
rm -rf var/ generated/
php bin/magento se:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; // 755 permission for directory  
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chown -R :<web server group> 
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

Run all below command and check again.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml rm -rf pub/static/_cache rm -rf var/cache rm -rf var/composer_home rm -rf var/generation rm -rf var/generated rm -rf var/page_cache rm -rf var/view_preprocessed rm -rf var/log rm -rf var/report rm -rf generated/code/ rm -rf generated/metadata/

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Also, Follow this Link for more information - [Frontend is breaks on magento 2.4.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354434/frontend-is-breaks-on-magento-2-4-3/354445#354445)